# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'databricks' in virtual environment with databricks-connect installed

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, databricks, databricks-connect

I am trying to use databricks connect.

I have installed databricks-connect version 9.1.39 in a virtual environment within my python project.

I have selected the python3.8 file in the virtual environment as the interpreter of the vscode project. However, when trying to run a file that starts with

`from databricks.connect import DatabricksSession`

I always get a

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'databricks'`

Just to make sure this was not due to the module databricks-connect not being in the actual environment when I run it, I actually opened a python shell within the venv and run the same line (`from databricks.connect ...`) and got the same error.

Why is this happening? Is it due to datarbicks.connect not being related to databricks-connect?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The `DatabricksSession` exists only in the [Databricks Connect V2](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html) that is designed for Databricks Runtime 13 or higher.  If you use DBR 9.1, then you need to follow up [instructions for DBR 11.3 and lower](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect-legacy.html) - in this case you need to configure connection details using `databricks-connect configure` command and just use normal Spark Session creation:

```
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

Comment: I have installed databricks-connect but when i run databricks-connect configure it fails with below

  File "C:\Users\kumarr36\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\databricks-connect.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark.databricks_connect'
PS C:\hdp-pfs-framework-lbr> pip show databricks-connect
Name: databricks-connect
Version: 13.1.0
Summary: Databricks Connect Client
Home-page:
Author: Databricks
Author-email: feedback@databricks.com
License: Databricks Proprietary License

Any suggestion here???

Comment: Package is used as: from databricks.connect import DatabricksSession